# How to access partition key from an existing table in cosmos db

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to access only partition key of an existing collection in cosmos db
I have gone through official doc and git hub links but no luck. Please help me.
Note: I'm able to successfully read and write data using java by using Document Client(SQL api)

Comment: Is it Table API or SQL API? In title you mentioned Table, but in description you mentioned SQL API. Both are different. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/introduction#next-steps

Comment: Edited my question. I'm using SQL api

Comment: Check if this is what you want https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.documentcollection.getpartitionkey?view=azure-java-stable#com_microsoft_azure_documentdb_DocumentCollection_getPartitionKey__

Comment: Do you want to get partition key of your collection?

Comment: Yes Steve I want to get partition key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
DocumentClient dClient = new DocumentClient(endPoint,primary_key,null,null);
String collectionLink = String.format("/dbs/%s/colls/%s", databaseId, collectionId);
ResourceResponse<DocumentCollection> response = dClient.readCollection(collectionLink,new RequestOptions());
DocumentCollection documentCollection = response.getResource();
PartitionKeyDefinition partitionKeyDefinition = documentCollection.getPartitionKey();
Collection<String> paths = partitionKeyDefinition.getPaths();
if(paths.iterator().hasNext()){
    System.out.println(paths.iterator().next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this works:
_container is the db container for cosmos.

```
        var settings = await _container!.ReadContainerAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        var partitionKeyPath = settings.Resource.PartitionKeyPath[1..];

        var partitionProperty = typeof(T).GetProperty(partitionKeyPath);
        var partitionKey = partitionProperty!.GetValue(message)!.ToString();
```